# Opendialog for showing Removable disks in c#

Tags: c#

I want to show a open dialog for the user, where the user can select only the files from the removable disks in the system. I am using the below code. But i need to get the Guid of removable disk to open the dialog.

Tell me how...

```
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dls = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
dls.CustomPlaces.Clear();
foreach (DriveInfo Drive in ListDrives)
{
    if (Drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
    {
        dls.CustomPlaces.Add(-----Guid of Drive------);
    }
    dls.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer how to get the Guids for the removable drives, however setting the `CustomPlaces` collection will not restrict your users from selecting anything but the folders in the collection, they will simply show up as shortcuts on the left of the open file dialog, and then only if you have the `AutoUpgradeEnabled` proptery set to `true` and your users are running Windows Vista or higher.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397814.aspx

Although, to finish off where you started, use the `DriveInfo.Name` to create a new entry in your custom places:

```
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dls = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
dls.CustomPlaces.Clear();
foreach (DriveInfo Drive in ListDrives)
{
    if (Drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
    {
        dls.CustomPlaces.Add(Drive.Name);
    }
    dls.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: I already tried by giving Drive.Name, but the dialog opens the path of application which is in some other drive.

Comment: if you want to *open* the dialog in *removable drive* in beggning then try setting **dls.InitialDirectory = item.Name;**

Answer (score 3):

Karthik, a better approach will be to get the path of selected file and check if it is from removable drive.

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.CustomPlaces.Clear();
        foreach (var item in System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (item.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                ofd.CustomPlaces.Add(item.RootDirectory.ToString());
        }

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
            string s = f.Directory.Root.ToString();
            DriveInfo df = new DriveInfo(s);
            if (df.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
            {
                //DO STUFF WITH FILE
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

WMI provides access to the GUID of a disk drive through the DeviceID property of the [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132.aspx) class.

WMI queries are performed using the [ManagementObjectSearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher_members.aspx) or one of the other query methods described in the documentation.

As I don't have access to VS right now, I can't provide a code sample though  I'm sure MSDM has one.